# I would like to get rid of the pink outline (path tracing) and white lines in the image below

Tags: inkscape, shapes, path-effects, outline, tracing

[image]

This image was a png which i filled in colour and edited its outline using Inkscape. However, once it's complete i could see that the outline pink in colour can be seen even after i filled with blue colour and there also some white lines that can be seen.

Comment: You should post the original too. I have a feeling it would be easier to edit it more carefully from the original, rather than edit this current version. And a vector application like Inkscape is not ideal for editing a raster image. That's how you get the quality in your example image. But also, is it possible you could get a vector version of this icon somewhere? If you can get svg, pdf, ai, or eps ...It's likely way easier to change the colors.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily fix that with a PNG file.

Instead, download [this](https://thenounproject.com/term/fist/52729/) as SVG, which is a vector format and lets you edit these things properly (make sure you check out their [terms of use](https://thenounproject.com/legal/#!terms-of-use) if you're using this for commercial work).

Open the SVG in Inkscape and then you're just a few clicks away from a clean fist icon, in whatever color you need and with clean, sharp edges.

[image]